# How does try...catch work?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am curious how does `try...catch` work in certain cases?

Let's assume I got some SQL code to execute, and I want those few instructions to fail if some of preceding fails.

So:

```
DECLARE @Sql1 VARCHAR(MAX) = 'Some sql statement',
        @Sql2 VARCHAR(MAX) = 'another sql statement',
        @Sql3 VARCHAR(MAX) = 'and another sql statement',

BEGIN TRY
       EXECUTE sp_executesql @Sql1
       EXECUTE sp_executesql @Sql2
       EXECUTE sp_executesql @Sql3
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
       ....
END CATCH
```

If `@Sql1` fails to execute what will happen with `@Sql2` and `@Sql3`?

Am I able to somehow stop execution of `@Sql2` and `@Sql3` if `@Sql1` fails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your scenario,

1. If @Sql1 fails to execute what will happen with @Sql2 and @Sql3?

   @Sql2 and @Sql3 will not execute if @Sql1 fails.
2. Am I able to somehow stop execution of @Sql2 and @Sql3 if @Sql1 fails?

   No need to stop @Sql2 and @Sql3 since if @Sql1 fails then your control is transferred to catch block. So you no need to explicitly stop the rest of the statements.

Note:

If there are no errors in the code that is enclosed in a TRY block, when the last statement in the TRY block has finished running, control passes to the statement immediately after the associated END CATCH statement. If there is an error in the code that is enclosed in a TRY block, control passes to the first statement in the associated CATCH block. If the END CATCH statement is the last statement in a stored procedure or trigger, control is passed back to the statement that called the stored procedure or fired the trigger.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,you can get more info by replacing below statements with dml

```
begin try
select 1--no error
select 1/0--error
select 1
select 1/0
select 1
end try
begin catch
raiserror('didvide by zero execption',16,1);
end catch
```

As per documentation of try catch ,on error  control will be transferred to catch block,that is what you can observe by using above statements.

Further note 1 is being printed which means entire batch is not aborted.You can take care of this by adding  like below

```
begin try
begin tran
select 1
select 1/0
select 1
select 1/0
select 1
commit
end try
begin catch
rollback
raiserror('didvide by zero execption',16,1);
end catch
```

or

```
set xact_abort on
begin try
begin tran
select 1
select 1/0
select 1
select 1/0
select 1
commit
end try
begin catch

raiserror('didvide by zero execption',16,1);
end catch
```